# combining the two queries and adding return to array

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two queries

the first is

```
select image from product where product_id = '82';
```

which returns

```
data/1B.png
```

the second is this

```
select image from product_image where product_id = '82';
```

which returns

```
data/computer_system.png
data/post-image.png
data/13D.png
```

So i tried to combine them and i get in this query

```
select p.image, pi.image as additional_images from product as p join product_image as pi on pi.product_id=p.product_id where p.product_id = '82'
```

which returns this

```
 data/1B.png    data/computer_system.png
 data/1B.png    data/post-image.png
 data/1B.png    data/13D.png
```

I need either a query that will return the 4 locations and then setting them to a php array $images

any ideas....i know i can do the queries separately as i have above but would i just do an array_merge....but is there a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select image from product where product_id = '82'
union
select image from product_image where product_id = '82';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use group_concat

```
select p.image, group_concat(pi.image) as additional_images 
from product as p 
join product_image as pi on pi.product_id=p.product_id 
where p.product_id = '82'
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat